# How to change 6 commits into 2 from feature branch to main branch

Tags: git, commit

I'm new to git so this might sound like a silly question. I have a master branch and a feature branch.

A->B->C->D(HEAD of master)

From C I created a feature branch 
C->M->N->O->P->Q->R(Head of feature branch)

Now i need to merge my feature branch to the master branch but i want that the six commits that i made in my feature branch don't reflect in my master instead there should only be two commits.
How can we do so?

I want the changes of both the branches to be in my master branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1: Rebase your master

Checkout Feature branch and after your checkout run:
`git pull --rebase origin master`

If merges are necessary, perform them, commit and run `git rebase --continue`

Your Feature branch will look like this:
`C-D-M-N-O-P-Q-R`

## Step 2: Squash

Run: `git rebase -i HEAD~6`
6 is because you want to squash the last 6 commits.

First commit is "pick"
All the other are "s" (for squash)

## Step 3: Push into repo

Perform `git push -f` on the feature branch to push it and the new history into the repo.

Force-push is necessary due to squashing and you rewriting the git history.

## Step 4: Merge into master

Checkout your master branch and run `git merge <feature-branch>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout feature branch with `git check feature_branch`
2. Squash `C->M->N->O->P->Q->R` to `C->S` with `git rebase -i C` or git rebase -i `HEAD~6`
3. Do rebase on master with `git rebase master`
4. Checkout master with `git checkout master`
5. Merge feature branch to master with `git merge feature_branch`

---

### Note:

> *(If you've push feature_branch to remote, you also have to do `git push -f` on feature_branch to overwrite the remote feature_branch)*